# Reference attribute in Firebase

Tags: firebase

Does firebase provide reference attribute concept?

If I want to notify my online status (online | offline | away) status to all my friends list where I am part of, one easy to implement is to define reference attribute say user@status and if its value is changed it could trigger change status where ever it is defined. Can this be achieved in Firebase?

I am trying to implement chat user status updates. We have user list maintained

Users/user-id-1/[user-id(friend),name,online-status],[user-id(friend),name,online-status], ...

Users/user-id-2/[user-id(friend),name,online-status],[user-id(friend),name,online-status], ...

If a particular user comes online then currently we need to update his status to all their users manually in a loop so that they get status updates...

Is there a better way to implement such backend triggers where if one field is changed update other fields... Can we define such rules or define some kind of reference pointers?

Answer (score 0):

```
users
   uid_1234
     email: thing@yipee.com
     online: true
  uid_5678
     email: stuff@yahoo.com
     online: false
```

Each user observes the users node for changes.

When a user logs on, set the online status to true. All other users will be notified that this users status changed and can update their UI accordingly.

Side note: add a onDisonnect observer to a users online status node when they log on to set it to false upon disconnect.