# Swift: Adding Additional Information on Firebase.createUser

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm new to Firebase backends (coming over from Parse), and I'm adding users with the `createUser(email:String, password:String, ...)` function. I'd like to have users be able to sign up (and sign in) with an additional "username" field. Is there a built-in way to do this, or should I do something along the lines of: creating a path for each user ID, and set the username there?

Comment: No, there is no built in way to do this. Also, questions similar to this have been asked before... Here's a snappy one with an answer [Reference attribute in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570272/reference-attribute-in-firebase/33573914#33573914). If you haven't done so, you should also review the [User Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html) section on the Firebase website, about 1/2 way down in the Storing User Data Section. That should get you going.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I didn't really know the best search terms given my inexperience with this kind of backend. @Jay thank you for the helpful links.